# "View any coupon of any type " permission for anonymous reduces the Score in acquia

Tags: 7, commerce, users

In my e-commerce website, anonymous user can't able to view the add coupon field until and unless I gave `"View any coupon of any type"` permission. Because its having notice like this: `Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.` Acquia Reduced the score of our website.So any other way is there to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem that Acquia have reduced this "score"? Or are you just worried about the potential security implications?

Answer (score 0):

The Acquia Insight tool (I am assuming you are referring to that score) is a tool that helps you find potential problems in your website and configuration. It is an automated tool that performs simple checks. It is a guide and a tool. Not exact science. (It could throw a false positive.)

However in my installation of `Commerce Coupon 7.x-2.0-rc2`, there is also the permission to `Redeem any coupon` (and the per type `Redeem <type> coupons` permission). And that works for anonymous user as well. Perhaps you should try that instead?